# Give permission to List item in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, splistitem

I want to restrict users to view list items which are not created by them.

Example: If I create a list item in a document library, Only I can view it,  others should not see that information)

Is there any way to complete this task?

Comment: Are you allowed to use server side code? In that case I would hock up an event receiver on the library that on ItemCreated breaks permissions on the item and assign permissions only to the creator of it.

Comment: I don't have much permission to the site to customize site and list item. I can write only client side javascript. If coding  can work means. Please tell me where to start and write code?

Comment: I do not think you can use client-side code (since you can not elevate permissions, your user would need to have "Manage Permissions" rights)

Comment: if i want to complete this in server side code? How to do that.? Any reference

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39249/eventreciever-to-change-permissions has the most of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage the permissions at List level for this and even at item level.

First of all, Goto List settings > Permissions > Stop inheriting Permissions.

For settings List item level permissions you can see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/sharepoint-list-item-permissions) link in our forum.

[Help Link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA101805400.aspx)

Please let me know if you have any other query.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a list, not a document library, then you can do this:

Go to list settings -> advanced settings ->
Read access:   Specify which items users are allowed to read
select: Read items that were created by the user.

Same setting for "edit access". On document libraries this option is not available, I don't know why. There you could try using "Target Audiences" but I have no experience with that. I read that it only restricts the access on UI-Level. If users would try to access it via JSOM/CSOM this would still work.

Comment: I tried your steps. Still others able to read list item which i created.

Comment: sorry I found out you need to additionally : Goto List settings > Permissions > Stop inheriting Permissions. Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view for the list with a filter as `Created by: [Me]`.

Comment: This only hides it from the view, it is not a permission setting. Users can still find the items not created by themselfs by using another view, or by doing a search for example

Comment: Oh my, somehow my thoughts turned the question to how to limit the view on the page. I updated the answer, and at least some time ago this solution worked for me.

Comment: my scenario is : if list item created by me, then I only can view the list item value. Others shouldn't see the list item which i created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set item level permission dynamically based on user.
So you can create a workflow for that list in which condition is like current user is equal to Author and Action is Replace Item level permission.

http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Try, I hope it works.